# Table border is not working on Export to excel

Tags: html, css, excel

HTML table border is not working after exporting the excel sheet. It is coming as no border excel sheet.The result after generate the excel is,

[image]

But my expected result is,

[image]

I want to split it into two different sections. But it is not working in excel sheet.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cCzqn/1490/)

```js
$("[id$=myButtonControlID]").click(function(e) {
  window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent($('div[id$=divTableDataHolder]').html()));
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: skyblue;
  color: white;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<button id="myButtonControlID">Export Table data into Excel</button>
<div id="divTableDataHolder">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>ColumnOne </th>
      <th>ColumnTwo</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row1ColValue1</td>
      <td>row1ColValue2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row2ColValue1</td>
      <td>row2ColValue2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row1ColValue1</td>
      <td>row1ColValue2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row2ColValue1</td>
      <td>row2ColValue2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row1ColValue1</td>
      <td>row1ColValue2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row2ColValue1</td>
      <td>row2ColValue2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row1ColValue1</td>
      <td>row1ColValue2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row2ColValue1</td>
      <td>row2ColValue2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row1ColValue1</td>
      <td>row1ColValue2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row2ColValue1</td>
      <td>row2ColValue2</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("[id$=myButtonControlID]").click(function(e) {
    window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent( $('div[id$=divTableDataHolder]').html()));
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
table
{
    border: 1px solid black;    
}
th
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color:skyblue;
    color: white;  
}
td
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<button id="myButtonControlID">Export Table data into Excel</button>
<div id="divTableDataHolder">
<table border="1">
    <tr><th>ColumnOne </th><th>ColumnTwo</th></tr>
<tr>
<td>row1ColValue1</td><td>row1ColValue2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>row2ColValue1</td><td>row2ColValue2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>row1ColValue1</td><td>row1ColValue2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>row2ColValue1</td><td>row2ColValue2</td>
</tr><tr>
<td>row1ColValue1</td><td>row1ColValue2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>row2ColValue1</td><td>row2ColValue2</td>
</tr><tr>
<td>row1ColValue1</td><td>row1ColValue2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>row2ColValue1</td><td>row2ColValue2</td>
</tr><tr>
<td>row1ColValue1</td><td>row1ColValue2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>row2ColValue1</td><td>row2ColValue2</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

I didn't test this could you please try this

Answer (score 0):

is it worked.
i modifiy this

```js
$("[id$=myButtonControlID]").click(function(e) {
    window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent( $('div[id$=divTableDataHolder]').html()));
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="myButtonControlID">Export Table data into Excel</button>
<div id="divTableDataHolder">
<table border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
    <tr><th>ColumnOne </th><th>ColumnTwo</th></tr>
<tr>
<td>row1ColValue1</td><td>row1ColValue2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>row2ColValue1</td><td>row2ColValue2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>row1ColValue1</td><td>row1ColValue2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>row2ColValue1</td><td>row2ColValue2</td>
</tr><tr>
<td>row1ColValue1</td><td>row1ColValue2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>row2ColValue1</td><td>row2ColValue2</td>
</tr><tr>
<td>row1ColValue1</td><td>row1ColValue2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>row2ColValue1</td><td>row2ColValue2</td>
</tr><tr>
<td>row1ColValue1</td><td>row1ColValue2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>row2ColValue1</td><td>row2ColValue2</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).